# MFC and threads. Skip Document/View and make my own solution?

Tags: c++, mfc, thread-safety

I am rewriting a MFC application to make it threadsafe. The application does not use the Document/View pattern and the data is not handled consistently. Some is only in the GUI, some in structs, some in XML.

So I want to handle the data in a consistent, threadsafe way. If I have all data in one struct it is easy to lock when needed.

So is it OK to skip the whole Document/View model and just separate data and presentation in my own way?

The application would work like this:

A communication stack is run in one thread, when a message is received it would lock the data and do necessary changes to it. It would then send a message to the main thread to tell it the GUI needs to be updated. The GUI would then lock the data and read it, then change the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is yes, it's OK to do that.  You can custom-write your own presentation completely, literally down to the pixel if you want.  Doing lock->data access->unlock->paint seems wise; depending on access time, you might be able to paint inside the lock as well, or update a DIB in the lock for painting outside of your lock... you have lots of options...